# Collection as data type in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one is `students` and the other is `courses`

the key for `courses` will be ID, however I'm having trouble connecting students with courses.

I need a datatype that will be similar to a list

so I can push an `id` into the data type or remove the `id`

also, I need a way to return * from `courses` if the `id` exists in the data type

Comment: You're better off breaking off your "list" into separate IDs by student.

Comment: What you need is a "many-to-many" relationship. RADAR's answer is the best (and simplest) way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a junction table **`StudentCourseAssoc`**

```
StudentCourseAssoc
----------------------
studentId  
courseId
```

The columns being foreign keys to students to courses respectively.

Comment: Never used a foreign key before, I'm assuming it 'links' the table by running a validation check to make sure that `studentid` correlates to a student inside my student table?

Comment: @Cody Jones, yes you are right, it makes sure that corresponding rows exists in students and courses table

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you work with a relational database.

(It's possible to put comma separated values in a `varchar` field and use to join against a table, but it's slow and complicated to use. I have seen such attempts from time to time, and it quickly falls apart when you want to do anything other than the simplest possible queries.)

Add another table, where you reference a course and a student. Example:

```
StudentCourses
-------------------
StudenCourseId     int    autoincrement
StudentId          int
CourseId           int
```

(The autoincrement key for the relation table is optional, you can omit it and make the combination of the two foreign keys the key of the table.)

To get the courses for a student you join in the relation table. Example:

```
select
  c.CourseName
from
  Courses c
  inner join StudentCourses sc on sc.CourseId = c.CourseId
where
  sc.StudentId = 42
```